# how to scroll textblok horizontally in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, scroll, textblock

I'm trying to scroll a large textblock horizontally. I tried couple of the following way. None of the works for me. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Try 1:-

```
             <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Height="590" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="520" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="522" Height="62" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlock111111222222" Width="590" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Canvas>
```

Try 2:-

```
          <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Height="590" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="520" Height="100" Name="stackPanel1" Width="635">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" Margin="1,1,1,1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="522" Height="62" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlock111111222222" Width="590" />
            </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
```

Try 3:-

```
            <Grid Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="500" Height="200" Name="grid1" Width="640">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="500" Height="100" Name="stackPanel1" Width="635">

                <ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" Margin="1,1,1,1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="500" Height="62" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlockTextBlock111111222222" Width="590" />
                </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Please simplify your examples, it is almost impossible to work out where each differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <TextBlock Width="1000" Height="500" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="asasdgasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If I understood correctly this should solve your problem.